# 301 Only Part of the URL in Nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

Trying to 301 a url by matching just its post id. For example I just want to rewrite any url that ends in -158436, yet I can't seem to make it work out.

```
    location /forum/this-stuff-does-not-matter-158436 {
    rewrite ^ http://www.thegoodurl.com/whatever/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `location ~ /forum/.*-158436$ {
    rewrite ^ http://www.thegoodurl.com/whatever/ permanent;
}`?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: No it didn't, yet I can't seem to see a reason why it wouldn't.